# Casual playing of Magic the Gathering MTG

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building, mtg-multiplayer

me and my GF started playing casual MTG together. I used to play so I know alot about the game and i taught her already so we know about playing. I had alot of cards from past but now we bought "a set of 3000 cards". They are mostly common, uncommon, few rares and its mostly War of the Spark, Throne of eldraine and so on. So now we are digging into this pile of cards but we are kinda lost about what should we do.

I was thinking about some page or a software, where I could put all the cards and it would tell me what decks consist of some of my cards so I could buy the rest or something like that.

Also we were looking at the Duel decks, but there are so many and alot of people say that they are unbalanced or not worth for the money.

Or should we just find decks lists we like and go buy them to our local store?

We have lot of cards, but kinda dont know what to do with them, because most of all they are commons and uncommons.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. I must admit I'm struggling to work out what you're trying to achieve here - MtG is a game which can be played in a large variety of ways, from very casual "play the cards you have and just have fun" on the kitchen table, through semi-competitive settings like FNM to ultra-competitive tournaments. What you should do depends entirely on where you want to fall on that scale.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering. I meant casual like playing at home with my GF and friends. As I said i have alot of cards in my colection but im not sure, if they are actualy usable. We like to play more interesting decks, not just basic starting decks. For example we bought the Mu Yanling planeswalker deck which was kinda basic and then we bought the Ashiok planeswalker deck which was more interesting. So the best way would be finding a software or some website where I could put my whole collection and it would tell me if there are any decks made of these cards so I can just buy the rest.

Comment: One thing to watch out for: a deck can be *interesting* (subjective, but perhaps related to combos or unusual gimmicks), and a deck can be *powerful* (good at winning tournaments). If you search for arbitrary decks online, you may end up with tournament decks which are probably **not** what you want because they'll prioritize being powerful over being interesting (though they may be both), and also they'll be expensive to construct (because MtG tournaments are worth serious money, thus so are the decks that can win them).

Comment: Also note that for casual play, you can just *proxy* cards you don't own - often by taking a cheap card like a land and then either drawing on it or putting it in a sleeve behind a printout of the card you want. (In which case you *can* reasonably make some high-level tournament decks to try out.)

Comment: Well proxying card isnt a possibility, cause im kinda a true collector myself. :D And yea, tournnament 100+€ decks arent the thing I want. 
I will give an example. We were looking at the duel decks which are usualy like 30€. So something around that or higher is good i would say. But I kinda wanted to use the cards i already have in my colection. There are so many products (boosters, booster boxes, precon decks and soooo many decks on the internet). So i really am kinda lost. The duel deck idea was very interesting to me, because it should be two decks balanced to duel each other.

Comment: Related to Benjamin's point above about different deck types: [Timmy, Johnny and Spike](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/making-magic/timmy-johnny-and-spike-2013-12-03).

Answer (score 5):

This may be closed as opinion-based, but there isn't a "right way" to play MTG casually or to build decks. However, I find that you are approaching it from the wrong point of view, and are missing out on what is (in my opinion) the most fun part about playing Magic, which is the deck-building.

Sure you can find a deck list online that uses some of your cards and just build a deck that someone else has thought of. But then you are only getting half of what Magic has to offer... you are getting the play-the-game part, but you are missing out on the build-the-deck part.

My recommendation would be to avoid looking at any deck lists, and instead just look through the cards you have. Get some ideas based on the cards you have and then build the best deck you can with only the cards you have. Of course it won't be as strong of a deck as it would if you were buying whatever specific cards you need to make a great deck, but it should be balanced against the deck that your girlfriend made since it came from the same pool of cards.

It sounds from the question wording like you are thinking of a Magic deck as one of a bunch of different possibilities that you can find and use. But really a Magic deck is any set of at least 60 cards that doesn't contain more than 4 of the same card (except basic lands). So there's no "right" or "wrong" decks to make, there are just ones which will win more often or be more fun to play. But challenging yourself to build a deck without the ability to just use any card you can think of can be a lot of fun.

The one thing you may need to get outside of the cards you already have is basic lands, depending on what basic lands your collection came with. You can get a lot of these very cheap, but you will need several of them to build almost any deck.

Comment: That actualy sounds right. I just wonder what would be the best way to learn how to build decks in general? I mean I personaly "kinda know how" but i was bit struggeling to teach my GF that. :D

Comment: A question about how to learn deckbuilding skills would be a good question for this site, but please ask it as a separate question, not as a comment on Gendolkari's answer. Please review our existing [deck-building questions](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deck-building?tab=Votes) and if you don't find your answer there, ask your question. Thanks!

Comment: I'd even dare to say that deck-building is one of the most fun, if not the most, part of allTCGs and CCGs. Yeah, playing the decks is also important and fun, but the moment you get hooked you start wondering "hey, what if I use this other card instead of..." and that is where the real joy begins :) the thrill of pulling the card you wanted from a booster pack, checking endless boxes and cards other players have to see if they have the one you seek and want to trade, etc... it goes beyond "merely" grabbing a pre-constructed deck and playing it.